# VS Code - open a file using the same window and keeping the workspace

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I want a way to open/create files from the terminal - using the same VS Code Window.

If I try to give the following command using the terminal, it'll close the current window and open a new one.

```
code . nameofthefile.js -r --reuse-window
```

Then, if I'm running npm start - the previous command will kill it. On top of this - it'll reload my workspace removing all the folders that were in the Explorer on the left bar.

If I use only ..

```
code . nomeofthefile.js
```

- this will open a new window. That's not what I want as well.

Is it possible to open a new file without closing the current with a terminal command in VS Code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Open a folder in current vs code window** while you are using the vs code terminal to change the directory:-
`code -r .`

Comment: Yes, it's not only important to open a folder in the current window (if you have no folders open in the workspace, the bar at the bottom of vscode will be purple), but you must ensure the file you are trying to open is somewhere within the open folder's child directories.

Answer (score 12):

The VSCode command line (`code`) is able to open both folders and files depending on the path you provide. If you provide multiple paths, it will open all of them. If a path does not exist, it will create a new file for you at that location.

```sh
# open current folder as workspace
code .

# open file.js in the last used workspace
code file.js # or
code -r file.js

# open file.js inside current folder as workspace
code . file.js
```

Thus,  according to the example you provided, you need to run `code nameofthefile.js` or
`code -r nameofthefile.js` (they both seem to do the same thing) to not override your current workspace.

Comment: omg.... just have to remove the "." lol
Ty very much!!!!

Comment: It took me a silly amount of time to remember that I'm no longer using VSC and instead using Cursor. So `cursor -r` is what I needed. ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

To open a folder/file from the terminal *in the same VSC window*, do the following:

**If you are in the folder/file directory:**

```
code -r .
```

**If you are NOT in the folder/file directory:**

```
code -r folder/file-name
```

Replace **folder/file-name** with the name of your *folder* or *file*. If it's a *file* don't forget to add the extension.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple **open** command.

```
open filename.dart
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `-add` to add it to the current directory and workspace:

`code --add /path/to/directory`

HT ChatGPT

*Please tell me the command line command to open a directory in  the current visual studio code window and have it add automatically added to the current workspace*

Comment: chatgpt. and this just misunderstands the question? the question is about files- not directories. funnily, it's not even chatgpt hallucinating a wrong answer. you fed it the wrong question. also, I think this is a multi-root workspace thing.